# Which VUE Datatables are similar to jQuery Datatables

Tags: laravel, vue.js, datatables

I'm using Laravel and on top jQuery with Datatables (https://datatables.net/) and i have to switch to VUE 2 where i'm searching for a similar Datatables Framework since i'm using a ton of all the functions of jQuery Datatables. Does anybody know which one could be used to have at least

- Column Grouping
- Customs rendering Columns
- Sum and Category Sums
- Custom Icons
- Custom Columns
- Drag & Drop of Rows (moving Rows)
- Export CSV, PDF, XLS
- Inline editing
- Responsive (With the "+" sign
  at the beginning of the Row - scrolling ist not prefered
- Fixed Header
- Scroller
- Server sided loading
- Sorting, Searching per Column
- Master-Detail Tables

I'm using a lot more but this is at least what i would need for every project - i looked at ag-grid but i this is pretty expensive since i use it for all future projects ... is there anything out there which is comparable to datatables?

Comment: this one is quite similar: https://www.npmjs.com/package/vuejs-datatable

Comment: thx luigi i'll have look!

Comment: hi luigi, i looked at the package but it seems that it can only fulfill a fraction of the jQuery Datatables - are there any compareable Frameworks out there?

Comment: Try https://github.com/niiknow/vue-datatables-net - which is a wrapper for jQuery DataTables or go native with bootstrap-vue b-table and this plugin https://github.com/niiknow/bvtnet-items-provider